# Can't get count of a json array from symfony 2.7 via ajax call

Tags: json, symfony

I need to get the count of a JSON array returned by symfony 2.7 controller action.

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace Eagle\ShopBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CartController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/cart/add")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function addAction(Request $request) {
        $items = Array(
            166 => Array(
                'quantity' => 2,
                'price' => 7
            ),
            165 => Array(
                'quantity' => 1,
                'price' => 7
            )
        );

        //convert to json using "JMSSerializerBundle"
        $serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
        $jsonproducts = $serializer->serialize($items, 'json');
        return new Response($jsonproducts);
    }   

}
```

And this is my ajax call,

```
    $.post("http://localhost:8000/cart/add", function (data) {
        alert(data.length);
    });
```

I need to get the count of items from `array(2)`, but I get `63` inside alert box.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, you got string in response. You need smth like:

```
$.post("http://localhost:8000/cart/add", function (data) {
    var json   = $.parseJSON(data); //parsing response string into JSON Object
    var length = Object.keys(json).length; //A little bit crappy way to get JSON Object length, but it works
    alert(length);
});
```

Or, of course you could use the way provided by @Put12co22mer2 - it is even better.

Answer (score 2):

*If you return a response , the 63 is the number of chars in the string (actually the response is a html string)* ... 
You've to return a [JsonResponse](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response)

You don't need the `@Template()`

Something like :

```
<?php

namespace Eagle\ShopBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse; //  <---- LOOK HERE

class CartController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/cart/add")
     */
    public function addAction(Request $request) {
        $items = Array(
            166 => Array(
                'quantity' => 2,
                'price' => 7
            ),
            165 => Array(
                'quantity' => 1,
                'price' => 7
            )
        );

        return new JsonResponse($jsonproducts);  //  <---- LOOK HERE
    }  
}
```